# Problems when reading bytes from a midi file

Tags: c++, file

I want to read the single bytes of a midi file, and I wrote a simple program to try to do that:

```
ifstream file{"D:\Descargas\OutFile.midi" };

if (!file.is_open())
    cout << "Not open" << endl; // It passes this test

char c;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    file >> c;
    cout << c << endl; // Output is -52, but it must output 4D which is 77 in decimal
}
```

but as I wrote, the output is not good and I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: You should open the file as binary or there's a good chance that you'll get bad results when the file happens to contain a 0x0d/0x0a sequence or a 0x1a byte.

Comment: @MichaelBurr why is that those sequences will break the rule? I noticed that if instead of `file >> c` I put `file.read(&c, 1)` then it works as expected, but I don't know *why*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the output to print in *hexedecimal* and to pad each number with `0` to a width of `2`. Also you need to cast the character `c` to  an `int` so it doesn't get output as a letter:

```
// configure output
cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::uppercase;

char c;

// read in the while block so you only use it if the read succeeds
while(file >> c) 
{
    // set the width and convert to an integer
    cout << std::setw(2) << int(c) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually was that the `\` character must be escaped.

Comment: Little known tip - at the API level, Windows will accept "/" as a path separator (it generally doesn't at the command line). This alternative to escaping the backslashes should work as well, and I find it more readble: `ifstream file{"D:/Descargas/OutFile.midi" };`